# Using ComboBox for changing Jpanels Jtables

Tags: sql, swing, sqlite, user-interface, jpanel

Im new in Java GUI and i have a problem with combining ComboBox with my Jtable on Jpanel. I want to make 5 Jpanels with 1 Jtable on each of them that takes data from online SQLite database and using combobox to switch between Jpanels. Could someone give me some example how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using combobox to switch between Jpanels.

Use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between panels. The tutorial example shows you exactly how to do this.

The other approach is to use a [JTabbed Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html). Again the tutorial shows how to add a panel to a different tab.

Comment: Thx m8, helped alot =)